# How to make a string interpreted as a condition with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to use the following syntax to filter the list `operations`:

```
a = [ope for ope in operations if ope[0] == 1]
```

The `if` statement condition is variable and may contain multiple conditions:

```
a = [ope for ope in operations if ope[0] == 1 and ope[1] == "test"]
```

I use a function to build the condition and return it as a string:

```
>>>> c = makeCondition(**{"id": 1, "title": 'test'})
>>>> c
"ope[0] == 1 and ope[1] == 'test'"
```

Is there a way to integrate the `c` variable into the list filtering? Something like this (of course, the `c` variable is evaluated as a string in the below example):

```
 a = [ope for ope in operations if c]
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried `a = [... if eval(c)]`?

Comment: Why do you build the condition as a string? Making it a function or a lambda would make much more sense.

Comment: `a = [... if eval(c)]` does work, thanks @Chris! Consider adding your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. @tripleee: I don't get what you mean. Could you tell me more with a basic syntax example?

Comment: You could do `conditions[0] = lambda ope : ope[0] == 1` and so on. Fill up a list with all the conditions as lambda functions inside, then in the list comprehension, select the one condition you want to use with `a = [ope for ope in operations if conditions[0](ope)]`.

Comment: Have your function return the logical result and not a string. Then you can use it in your test. Do not generate a strong of code and then use `evel` -- pretty much ever...

Comment: @Jeronimo: I have several conditions in my case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, if you want to change the string to be considered as an expression, you can use `eval(string)`.

Comment: using eval is almost always the wrong solution. Here the problem can certainly be solved using lambdas instead

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is considered [unsafe](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and is generally avoided.

You can use `[filter][1]` with functions. For this you should put your test conditions in a function.

Here's an example to create a list of numbers between 1 and 100 that are multiples of 3 and 7

```
def mult3(n):
    return n % 3 == 0

def mult7(n):
    return n % 7 == 0

def mult3_and_7(n):
    return mult3(n) and mult7(n)

list(filter(mult3_and_7, range(1, 101)))
```

A more consice way is to use [lambdas](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk):

```
list(filter(lambda n: (n % 3 == 0) and (n % 7 == 0), range(1, 101))
```

The cool thing is you can chain filters like so:

```
list(filter(lambda n: n % 3 == 0, filter(lambda n: n % 7 == 0, range(1, 101))))
```

They all give `[21, 42, 63, 84]`

This approach should help you chain multiple conditions clearly.

Comment: This helps, thanks! But in my case, I need to collect the values associated to each key from the dictionnary passed as a **kwargs, not just True or False values.

Comment: In your case, `makeCondition` seems to be hard coded with `ope` this means that it may be refactored to something like `makeCondition(some_list, **kwargs) -> bool`. Rather than return a string, the tests take place inside `makeCondition`. That way, you can eaisly do `list(filter(makeCondition, ope))`.

Comment: I have made another post related to that subject : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47769705/2508539. Thanks again!