# How to filter a list of lists based on a variable set of conditions with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filtering

Question related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47709795/2508539).

I need help to filter a list of lists depending on a variable set of conditions.

Here is an extract of the list:

```
ex = [
    # ["ref", "type", "date"]
    [1, 'CB', '2017-12-11'],
    [2, 'CB', '2017-12-01'],
    [3, 'RET', '2017-11-08'],
    [1, 'CB', '2017-11-08'],
    [5, 'RET', '2017-10-10'],
]
```

I want to apply a final treatment like `list(filter(makeCondition, ex))` where `makeCondition(myList, **kwargs)` function returns a boolean that enables to filter the list.

I have troubles building this function as adviced in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47709795/2508539), as the number of conditions defined in the **kwargs dictionnary is variable.

Examples of conditions sets:

```
conditions = {"ref": 3}
conditions = {"ref": 1, "type": "CB"}
```

Here is a start:

```
def makeConditions(myList, **p):

    # For each key:value in the dictionnary
    for key, value in p.items():

        if key == "ref":
            lambda x: x[0] == value
        elif key == "type":
            lambda x: x[1] == value
        elif key == "date":
            lambda x: x[2] == value

    # return chained conditions...

list(filter(makeConditions, ex))
```

I don't get the logical idea that various comments attempted to give in the post mentioned above... Do I have to execute the `filter()` function for each sublist or is it possible to do it for the whole global list? Any advices will be very welcome!

Comment: will it have always ref, type and date, or is it variable?

Comment: The `conditions` variable is variable indeed, as shown in the post. The content of the sublists is always constant with the 3 objects: ref, type and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply make a function that returns the conditional:

```
def makeConditions(**p):
    fieldname = {"ref": 0, "type": 1, "date": 2 }
    def filterfunc(elt):
        for k, v in p.items():
            if elt[fieldname[k]] != v: # if one condition is not met: false
                return False
        return True
    return filterfunc
```

Then you can use it that way:

```
>>> list(filter(makeConditions(ref=1), ex))
[[1, 'CB', '2017-12-11'], [1, 'CB', '2017-11-08']]
>>> list(filter(makeConditions(type='CB'), ex))
[[1, 'CB', '2017-12-11'], [2, 'CB', '2017-12-01'], [1, 'CB', '2017-11-08']]
>>> list(filter(makeConditions(type='CB', ref=2), ex))
[[2, 'CB', '2017-12-01']]
```

Comment: It looks good and so much shorter... Thanks @Serge Ballesta! I'll have a closer look to it and come back.

Answer (score 0):

You was almost there, the idea is to create a list with the functions that checks the conditions you need, once you have them you can just call those functions over the list they have to check and use `all` function to check if all of them are evaluated to `True`, note the use of partial so the function in the `filter` call only takes the data list; check this:

```
from functools import partial

ex = [
    # ["ref", "type", "date"]
    [1, 'CB', '2017-12-11'],
    [2, 'CB', '2017-12-01'],
    [3, 'RET', '2017-11-08'],
    [1, 'CB', '2017-11-08'],
    [5, 'RET', '2017-10-10'],
]

conditions  = {"ref": 3}
conditions2 = {"ref": 1, "type": "CB"}

def apply(data, *args):
"""
same as map, but takes some data and a variable list of functions instead
it will make all that functions evaluate over that data
"""
  return map(lambda f: f(data), args)


def makeConditions(p, myList):
    # For each key:value in the dictionnary
    def checkvalue(index, val, lst):
      return lst[index] == val
    conds = []
    for key, value in p.items():
        if key == "ref":
            conds.append(partial(checkvalue, 0, value))
        elif key == "type":
            conds.append(partial(checkvalue, 1, value))
        elif key == "date":
            conds.append(partial(checkvalue, 2, value))
    return all(apply(myList, *conds)) # does all the value checks evaluate to true?

#use partial to bind the conditions to the makeConditions function
print(list(filter(partial(makeConditions, conditions), ex)))
#[[3, 'RET', '2017-11-08']]
print(list(filter(partial(makeConditions, conditions2), ex)))
#[[1, 'CB', '2017-12-11'], [1, 'CB', '2017-11-08']]
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AjarSelfassuredWhippoorwill)

> Do I have to execute the filter() function for each sublist or is it possible to do it for the whole global list?

Filter iterates over all the list aplying a function for each of the elements, if the function evaluates to True then the element will remind in the result, so **filter works over the whole global list**

Comment: Many thanks @Daniel Sanchez! Several new things to me in your suggestion, anyway it works very well. I have to read the doc about `partial()` function. I don't get how the `checkvalue()` function finds the `index` argument.

Comment: @wiltomap, partial binds values to functions arguments returning another function with those arguments fixed with those values, so when i call `partial(checkvalue, 0, value)` im creating a function that will do the same as your lambdas, just to be used afterwards.